# Element of a certain order in multiplicative group of residues

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

Let's say that $G$ is the multiplicative group of residues mod $p$, where $p$ is prime. I know that the order of an element $g \in G$ is the least $k$ for which $g^k \equiv 1 \mod{p}$.

How can we go about finding an element in this group with a particular prime order? That is, if we know $p$ and we also know that $k$ is prime, how can we find a $g \in G$ such that $ord_p(g)= k$?

I'm wondering if the fact that $k$ is prime can be useful for finding a more efficient method than if nothing is known about whether $k$ is prime or composite. The only thing I can think of is that if $k$ is prime then we know that it is one of the prime factors of $p-1$, not just any factor of $p-1$. But does this help find $g$?

Thanks a lot for any comments.

Comment: If we happen to know a primitive root $g$ (a generator of the group), then primality of $k$ is irrelevant, an answer is $g^{(p-1)/k}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, you're absolutely right. I hadn't thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: Even for quite large primes, there are good "probabilistic" algorithms for finding a primitive root.